# Is Tracing On in cassandra the right choice to track the timetaken in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, benchmarking, cassandra-3.0

When I try to execute the query on 500000 entries in a table, I could see that it is completed in 1200ms, But when I try to execute the query using TRACING ON enabled, I can see it is showing a long time in the Tracing log say 1850 ms.

So I would like to confirm whether the TRACING ON feature in Cassandra is a right choice for tracking time taken for executing queries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are metrics that will give you the amount of time spent on queries, you can most easily view it with `nodetool proxyhistograms` (doc) or grabbing directly from JMX. `TRACING ON` is for debugging *why* a request is slow. Its important to note that this is **very** expensive (and possibly adds time to query, although most tracing is async) and should be avoided outside of debugging issues.

You can also use `nodetool settraceprobability` to globally record some % of the queries, which you can then look at and maybe process with some tooling the events and sessions table in the `system_traces` keyspace.

Comment: Is that Tracing On a right feature to track the time of execution of a query? It provides the execution time, My question is, Is this the right utility to track the time taken for the query execution?

Comment: I observed that It is showing a longer execution time than the query actually takes without tracing on.

Comment: which is the right solution for tracking the query execution time in Cassandra

Comment: it works to track time of a single query entered manually, but it will differ from time to time.

Comment: So @chris Could you let me know the proper way to track the query execution time in Cassandra?

Comment: `nodetool proxyhistogram` or use a jmx tool to pull the metrics and aggregate it.

Comment: proxyhistograms give an average of the write latency right? I need for a particular query request.  @Chris

Comment: if you want to see what is happening on a particular query (once) then `TRACING ON` would work. Its more for debugging why a particular query is slow than to determine how fast it is because its incredibly expensive and a single query is not going to be a good sample of how it will perform. proxyhistograms will give more than just average, its a histogram of all requests so you can get min/max/99th percentile (99th probably mot important) etc. Theres a set of metrics CoordinatorReadLatency per table, so for your table if its dominated by that query you can see percentiles for multiple queries.

Comment: Thanks, @Chris, I accepted ur answer, Can you please check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47977824/understanding-read-from-a-single-partition-in-cassandra

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48018288/how-to-set-the-downgrading-policy-in-cassandra-using-nodejs Can you let me know this please?

Comment: you dont need to link your other questions in unrelated answers, theres people who watch the tags and will respond.

Answer (score 2):

Per documentation https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshTracing.html

> Enables and disables tracing for transactions on all nodes in the
>   cluster. Use tracing to troubleshoot performance problems. Detailed
>   transaction information related Cassandra internal operations is
>   captured in the system_traces keyspace. When a query runs a session id
>   displays in the query results and an entry with the high-level details
>   such as session id and client, and session length, is written to the
>   system_traces.session table.

So it should be used for troubleshooting performance and hence measuring time taken.

The tracing information consists of the activity, the timestamp at which the activity occurred, the source of the activity and the time elapsed since the start of the request (source_elapsed). source_elapsed is in microseconds.