# Understanding read from a single partition in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have a 3 node setup, Node1 (172.30.56.60), Node2 (172.30.56.61) and Node3 (172.30.56.62), 
It has the single partition data of 100K, the partition is framed by nodeip.
Please find the token / partition value for the nodeip - 172.30.56.60

```
cqlsh:qnapstat> SELECT token(nodeip) FROM nodedata WHERE nodeip = '172.30.56.60' LIMIT 5; 

 system.token(nodeip)
----------------------
   222567180698744628
   222567180698744628
   222567180698744628
   222567180698744628
   222567180698744628
```

As per the ./nodetool ring value provided below, '172.30.56.60' only will return the data to the coordinator since the value from 173960939250606057 to 239923324758894350 is handled bu the node 172.30.56.60. **Note : This is my understanding**

```
172.30.56.60  rack1       Up     Normal  32.72 MiB       100.00%             173960939250606057                          
172.30.56.62  rack1       Up     Normal  32.88 MiB       100.00%             239923324758894351                          
172.30.56.61  rack1       Up     Normal  32.84 MiB       100.00%             253117576269706963                          
172.30.56.60  rack1       Up     Normal  32.72 MiB       100.00%             273249439554531014                          
172.30.56.61  rack1       Up     Normal  32.84 MiB       100.00%             295635292275517104                          
172.30.56.62  rack1       Up     Normal  32.88 MiB       100.00%             301162927966816823
```

I have two questions here,

1) When I try to execute the following query, Does it mean that Coordinator (say 172.30.56.61) reads all the data from the 172.30.56.60?

2) Is that after receiving all the 100 K entries in the coordinator, Coordinator will perform the aggregation for 100K, If so does it keeps all 100K entries in memory in 172.30.56.61?

```
SELECT Max(readiops) FROM nodedata WHERE nodeip = '172.30.56.60';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nice tool called **CQL TRACING** that can help you understand and see the flow of events once a SELECT query is executed.

```
cqlsh> INSERT INTO test.nodedata (nodeip, readiops) VALUES (1, 10);
cqlsh> INSERT INTO test.nodedata (nodeip, readiops) VALUES (1, 20);
cqlsh> INSERT INTO test.nodedata (nodeip, readiops) VALUES (1, 30);
cqlsh> select * from test.nodedata ;

 nodeip | readiops   
--------+-----------
      1 |        10 
      1 |        20 
      1 |        30 

(3 rows)
cqlsh> SELECT MAX(readiops) FROM test.nodedata WHERE nodeip = 1;

 system.max(readiops)
-----------------------
                   30

(1 rows)
```

Now let's set `cqlsh> TRACING ON` and run the same query again.

```
cqlsh> TRACING ON
Now Tracing is enabled
cqlsh> SELECT MAX(readiops) FROM test.nodedata WHERE nodeip = 1;

 system.max(readiops)
----------------------
                   30

(1 rows)

Tracing session: 4d7bf970-eada-11e7-a79d-000000000003


 activity                                                                                                                                                        | timestamp                  | source       | source_elapsed
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+--------------+----------------
                                                                                                                                              Execute CQL3 query | 2017-12-27 07:48:44.404000 | 172.16.0.128 |              0
                                                                                                        read_data: message received from /172.16.0.128 [shard 4] | 2017-12-27 07:48:44.385109 |  172.16.0.48 |              9
                                                                                       read_data handling is done, sending a response to /172.16.0.128 [shard 4] | 2017-12-27 07:48:44.385322 |  172.16.0.48 |            222
                                                                                                                                   Parsing a statement [shard 1] | 2017-12-27 07:48:44.404821 | 172.16.0.128 |             --
                                                                                                                                Processing a statement [shard 1] | 2017-12-27 07:48:44.404913 | 172.16.0.128 |             93
 Creating read executor for token 6292367497774912474 with all: {172.16.0.128, 172.16.0.48, 172.16.0.115} targets: {172.16.0.48} repair decision: NONE [shard 1] | 2017-12-27 07:48:44.404966 | 172.16.0.128 |            146
                                                                                                          read_data: sending a message to /172.16.0.48 [shard 1] | 2017-12-27 07:48:44.404972 | 172.16.0.128 |            152
                                                                                                             read_data: got response from /172.16.0.48 [shard 1] | 2017-12-27 07:48:44.405497 | 172.16.0.128 |            676
                                                                                                                  Done processing - preparing a result [shard 1] | 2017-12-27 07:48:44.405535 | 172.16.0.128 |            715
                                                                                                                                                Request complete | 2017-12-27 07:48:44.404722 | 172.16.0.128 |            722
```

As for your questions:

1. The Coordinator passes the query to the replica, if `RF = 1` or (`RF > 1` and `CL=ONE`), than it will receive the reply from 1 replica, but if (`RF > 1` and `CL > 1`), than it needs to receive replies from multiple replicas and compare the answers, so there's also orchestration done on the Coordinator side.
   The way it is actually done is a data request to the fastest replica (using the snitch) and a digest request to the other replicas needed to satisfy the CL.
   And then the coordinator need to hash the responses from the data and digest requests and compare them.
   If the partition is hashed into a specific node, it will reside in that node (assuming RF=1) and information will be read only from that node.
2. The Client sends with the query the page size, so the reply itself is returned in bulks (default=5000), which can be set from the client side.

I recommend watching this [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HuDJBTPdaOA&list=PLm-EPIkBI3YorKfmT9LXpBhyeZMYAM1M7) clip on Cassandra read path for more details.

Comment: When I try to execute the following query, Does it mean that Coordinator (say 172.30.56.61) reads all the data from the 172.30.56.60? Can you answer this question?

Comment: Or Even the same partition's data will be read from many nodes?

Comment: The coordinator sends the query to the replica/s and the replica/s returns the data in bulks. and I did answered that, it depends on the RF + CL settings. Why did you vote -1?

Comment: I added more info and I hope that is the information you requested.

Comment: Okay, I gave an upvote, could you please clarify this, I have a cluster of 3 nodes, RF = 3 and WC=3, I store 100K entries in one partition,  Does it mean that all the three nodes will have 100K entries since it is within the same partition ?

Comment: Say If the coordinator is 172.30.56.61 and as per the ring (mentioned in the question) the node responsible for that particular partition is 172.30.56.60 : In this case, Does it mean that It reads all 100 K from 172.30.56.60 and perform the aggregation in the coordinator node in 172.30.56.61 ?

Comment: Also this sentence (The way it is actually done is a data request to the fastest replica - using the snitch ) is contradicting with the nodetool ring, I thought the partition and node mapping mentioned in the node tool ring is responsible for serving (read and write request) for that partitioned data but you are saying the read depends on the nearest node, How actually it works, please let me know

Comment: If the nearest node will server the read request, What is the point of nodetool ring be available ?

Comment: What is WC? Did you mean Consistency Level (CL)?
When using RF=3, that means all the data is replicated 3 times, and each of the 3 nodes holds ALL your DBs data. This means that any query to that partition can be served from any the 3 nodes.
Per the CL (1, Q, ALL) , the Coordinator needs to get the response from 1 / 2 / 3 servers. In 'ALL' the Snitch network awareness is not relevant, but in CL=Q (2 nodes must reply), the Snitch helps the Coordinator to choose the fastest 2 nodes. The fastest will get the data req and the 2nd the Digest req. The RING is also for HA purposes.

Comment: Please watch the youtube short lecture I sent you, it will make much more sense when you see it visually.