# How to bring up the new node

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, high-availability

It is a follow-up question from [High Availability in Cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48056093/high-availability-in-cassandra/48056759?noredirect=1#48056759)

1) Let's say we have three nodes N1, N2 and N3, I have RF =3 and WC = 3 and RC = 1, then which means I cannot handle any node failure in case of write.

2) Let's say If the N3 (Imagine It holds the data) went down and as of now we will not be able to write the data with the consistency as '3'.

Question 1: Now If I bring a new Node N4 up and attach to the cluster, Still I will not be able to write to the cluster with consistency 3, So How can I make the node N4 act as the third node?

Question 2: I mean let's say we have 7 node cluster with RF = 3, then If any node holding the replica went down, Is there a way to make existing other nodes in the cluster to act as a node holding the partition?

Comment: Replace N3 by N4.
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/opsReplaceNode.html

Comment: I mean let's say we have 7 node cluster with RF = 3, then If any node holding the replica went down, Is there a way to make existing other nodes in the cluster to act as a node holding the partition?

Comment: http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2017/05/23/auto-bootstrapping-part1.html
 
   
you may try this: 
https://blog.alteroot.org/articles/2014-03-12/replace-a-dead-node-in-cassandra.html

Comment: Why you're using consistency `ALL` for writes? If you're using it - then every time one of the nodes is down, you'll get problems writing data

Comment: @Harry if you are not replacing a node , any other node will not act as it.

Comment: @AlexOtt Let's say I have 7 nodes, N1 to N7 with RF =3 and Consistency as quorum (which means its 2). Consider N1 , N2 and N3 hold the data, If any two of replica holding the data goes down, Can't I do something with N4 to N7, I mean without adding a new node?

Comment: Only if you decommission node, then data will be re-distributed to other nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the docs:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsReplaceNode.html

You want to replace a dead node in your scenario. N3 should be removed from the ring and replaced by N4.

It should be easy to follow that instructions step by step. It is critial that if you installed the node via package mangement to stop it before configuring it new and to wipe out all existing data, caches and commitlogs from it (often found under `/var/lib/cassandra/*`).

Also it is possible to remove a dead node from the ring with `nodetool removenode` as described here http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsRemoveNode.html and here https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsRemoveNode.html - this removes the node from your cluster (and you should ensure that it cant come back after that before wiping out its data).

Remember it only removes a dead node from the ring and assigns the token ranges to the remaining nodes, but no streaming will happen automatically. You will need to rum `nodetool repair` after removing a dead node.

If you want to remove a live node you can use `nodetool decommission` - but as above, ensure the node does not reenter the cluster by wiping out it's data.

Update:

Nodes in Cassandra are not "named" in that fashion N1, N2, etc. internally. The nodes have an uuid and they own so called token ranges which they are responsible for.

If a node is down - simply repair it if possible at all, bring it online again to join it your cluster - if that took less than the default 3 hours you are fine. Otherwise run `nodetool repair`.

But if the node is 'lost' completely and will never come back, run `nodetool removenode` on that dead node. This asks cassandra to assign the token ranges the dead node was responsible for to the remaining nodes. After that run `nodetool repair` so the nodes will stream the data which is missing. After that your cluster will now have one node less, so it will be six nodes.

Comment: I got your point, I will accept your answer. Can you let me know, Is there a way in Cassandra to perform the remove node and repair by monitoring mechanism or configuration ?

Comment: (i.e) If a node goes down, Automatically makes another node (Example : N4 to N7) in the cluster to hold responsibility for that partition.

Comment: Not by default out of the box. And I would vote that doing so might be dangerous - for example what happens if a network switch partitons your cluster? One side would remove their nodes as the other side also and your cluster is broken. Don't use CL = RF in production, go with something like RF=5 and CL=QUORUM and just dont care if node goes down the driver will know that a node is unreachable and just use the other ones.

Comment: Thanks @Mandraenke, Do you know about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48072272/digest-request-in-cassandra?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a 7 node cluster. N1, N2, N3,  ... ,N7. Suppose you have a data . That has  RF = 3, Write consistency = 2, Read consistency = 2. Let's say node N1,N2, N3 are holding the data. If any of this nodes goes down,the cluster will be completely fine and data read/write operation will not be affected as long as consistency level for read and write operation is satisfied.

Suppose you have a data . That has  RF = 3, Write consistency = 3, Read consistency = 3. Let's say node N1,N2, N3 are holding the data. If any of this nodes goes down,the operations will fail as the consistency level is not satisfied.

Now you can do two things if any of the N1,N2,N3 goes down:
1) You can replace the node. In this case newly replaced node will act like old dead node.
2) You can manually add a new node N8 and remove the old dead node N3. In this case Cassandra will distribute it's partiotioner among the ring and resize partiotion.

Comment: Can't I do something with N4 to N7, I mean without adding a new node?

Comment: I can't add a new node, In this case, even the remaining N4 to N7 can't help?

Comment: First try to bring the node back online. If that cannot be done use `nodetool removenode` and `nodetool repair` on the remaining six nodes to reassign and restream the data. See addition to my answer.