# Digest request in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have few questions regarding the digest request, I read through the docs and the following informations are not up to the point,

1) Lets say I have 10 node cluster with the RF =3 and RC = 2,

Also for understanding let the Replicas be Node 1, Node 2 and Node 3 and Coordinator be Node 4.

For the read request, As per my understanding first coordinator (Node 4) sends the direct request to one of the node with the lower latency (Dynamic snitch) say Node 1 and gets the data, then after receiving the data It sends the digest request to one of the next latency node say Node 2 and gets only the hash and compares with the hash calculated from direct request.

**Ques 1** : Is the digest request send parallelley (to Node 2) with the direct request (Or) after receving the direct request It send the digest request ?

**Ques 2 :** I know the digest request for Node 3 also will be sent for data consistency, But when does the coordinator (Node 4) send the digest request to the third replica (Node 3) ? Is it after coordinator responding back to the client?

**Ques 3 :** Also It is mentioned in the doc only after completing the read repair the coordinator will respond back to the client?

**Ques 4 :** Apart from Tracing on, Could somebody explain the way to identify the read and write request flow in real time?

It would be Great, If you guys could explain these question with workflow, It will be useful for everyone.

I read through video also for reference : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HuDJBTPdaOA&list=PLm-EPIkBI3YorKfmT9LXpBhyeZMYAM1M7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming your situation. Here N4 is coordinator node. You sent direct request to N2(which is a replica). After receiving response from N2, coordinator node(N4) will send a digest request to any of the nodes(N3 or N1) that is containing other replica. Let's say N3 is nearer node. So, the digest request will be sent to N3 to satisfy consistency level. After receiving response from N3 , N4 will compare the datas from N2 and N3 and return the updated data to  the client.

There is another replica in N1 node. Now coordinator node sends digest request to all other replicas.(In this case N1). And if N4 finds, any node(N1, N2, N3) is not updated it runs a read repair request.

p.s: I don't know answer 4.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/dml/architectureClientRequestsRead_c.html

https://teddyma.gitbooks.io/learncassandra/content/client/read_requests.html

Comment: I am happy with your answer, So To explain it, Everything is sequential, 1) Direct request then after receiving response, 2) then only coordinator send digest request and receive the hash, 3) Considering same hash value it responds to the client 4) After responding to the client, It sends the request to the remaining replica and updates the read repair based on that. Is it correct?

Comment: Let me wait for the other ppl who can respond question 4, If they are not able to respond it, I will accept your answer

Comment: One additional note, read repair is not triggered after every read request but a tuneable by itself. See https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/opsRepairNodesReadRepair.html for details.

Comment: Q4: You can set the log level to trace in general and nonitor cassandra logs on all nodes, but thats no fun.

Comment: @Mandraenke I didn't understand this point in this blog : 'This means that for a consistency level of ONE, no data is repaired because no comparison takes place. For QUORUM, only the nodes that the query touches are repaired, not all nodes.'

Comment: As per my understanding, after the quorum read / one consistency read responds to the client, the coo0rdinator as a Final process, read the data from all the remaining replicas and perform the comparsion and do read repair, But as per these words in datastax, It seems to be wrong.

Comment: @Mandraenke why are you saying that digest request to all the remaining replicas will not happen everytime?

Comment: requesting a digest has some overhead - so if your read consistency is fulfilled sending all other nodes a digest request pushed additional load to your cluster, because those are digest are reads which involves disk io. Because of that it is only triggered on a small percentage.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162499/discussion-between-harry-and-mandraenke).

Comment: @ Harry,  discuss the conservation in chat, but please post the final output,  it will be beneficial to may people. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

For the 4th question, you can enable cass_log_set_level and set the log level to debug info and you can get the real time debug info.

Comment: How to set this cass_log_set_level ? I am not able to find in any of the files in cassandra conf folder @Chakri

Comment: You have to set it in the datastax driver and then do the queries through the program. Maybe, you can get the log info from logs file, if you want the log info without programming

Comment: Am using apache cassandra

Comment: You have to use a driver like c, or python (provided by datastax) to access cassandra through program

Comment: Go through this https://github.com/datastax/cpp-driver/blob/master/examples/logging/logging.c