# Retry policies in Cassandra using nodejs

Tags: node.js, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I finally have written a **retry policy for Cassandra in nodejs**, I have a use case where the whenever there is a one node replica available I need to allow the read and write by modifying my consistency to the minimum level.

I have attached my updated retry code (DowngradeRetryPolicy in retry.js), Could you please check the link and give your comments,

https://gist.github.com/harigist/f74b29976702a84f8f37e1bf7b509e0e

1) I expect the list of problems in using this retry policy?
2) Anything wrong with this code? Is there a change I need to make to handle corner cases?

Comment: Did you look to code of Java driver, for example, to see what corner cases they are handling - it's quite heavily documented

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a downgrading consistency retry policy causes your application consistency guarantee to be at minimum level. It would be theoretically equivalent to use a lower consistency level the first time.

I personally don't see much use for that type of policy except in the cases when you are handling a "normal mode" and "degraded mode" of your application.

About the code, it looks good to me.

Comment: Reason I used the downgrade retry policy: I have a dependency of two-node installation (with RF =2, Write Consistency =2, Read Consistency =2), In case of node failure, I need to support the write and read.

Comment: So Tell me one thing, If I have a one node failure then using the downgrade policy I will be able to perform write and read with the one cassandra node, Then After bringing the second node up, Will It automatically replicate all the data written in first node (during failure) to the second node (which we bought UP now)? Or do we need to perform node repair?

Comment: Hey @jorgebg, Could you please let me know?

Comment: This depends on downtime of that node - when node is not available, coordinator node will store "hints" that could be replayed when node is back (hinted handoff). But there are limitation on how long these hints are stored. See https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsRepairNodesHintedHandoff.html for more details.  If node was down for too long time, then you need to perform repair.

Answer (score 0):

Question...  as per the [docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/3.5/features/tuning-policies/) the policy interface consists of four methods:

`onReadTimeout`, `onUnavailable`, `onWriteTimeout`, and `onRequestError`

in your policy, i only see 3.  If any are omitted, what happens?  Is the default logic used?

Also, another thing I see you're not using in your code is a `_childPolicy`
https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver/blob/master/lib/policies/retry.js#L160

Comment: I think i have the answer ... `util.inherits(MyRetryPolicy, cassandra.policies.retry.RetryPolicy);` means inheriting the default policy :) . Great work, thanks!