# Connection pooling in apache cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Using the same **client** instance (One for each keyspace) for all the queries in the application, Will this scale in Cassandra?

```
const client = new cassandra.Client({ contactPoints: ['172.30.56.60','172.30.56.61','172.30.56.62'], keyspace: 'qnapstat',
                                      policies : { loadBalancing : new cassandra.policies.loadBalancing.RoundRobinPolicy
                                                 } });
```

Or Is it recommended to use new client instance for every query?

Please show some light?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't need to have client instance per query or keyspace - clients is very expensive to establish.  Client automatically handles all queries in parallel, even for different keyspaces. You may tune the number of connection to local/remote DCs, but the [default 1 per host](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/3.3/features/connection-pooling/) is quite good choice.

Comment: Client demands a keyspace right? So Do I need to create a client for every keyspace?

Comment: No, you can use one client, if all your queries are in the same keyspace, or queries use `keyspace.table` instead of `table` syntax

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48202044/retry-policies-in-cassandra-using-nodejs Can you explain the point I mentioned in the comment for jorgebg

Comment: Can you please check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48380766/secondary-index-in-apache-cassandra :)