# Secondary index in Apache Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0

I tried to understand the secondary Index in Cassandra using the following link:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BPvZIj5fvl4

Let's say we have 5 node N1, N2, N3, N4 and N5 cluster with Replication Factor of 3 which means a partition data will be replicated to 3 nodes in the cluster (say N1, N2 and N3).

Now when I execute this query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM user
WHERE partitionKey = "somedata" AND ClusteringKey = "test";
```

with the Read consistency as '2'

It will query from any two of the nodes N1, N2 or N3

If I apply a secondary index on any of the column, How many nodes will the following query be executed?

```sql
SELECT *
FROM user
WHERE partitionKey = "somedata" AND secondaryKey = "test";
```

I have two queries in this:

1. As per the video, the above query on secondary index will read from all the 5 nodes in the cluster for search on secondaryIndexColumn? Is it correct?
2. Will there be any other performance impact in using secondary Index? - It would be Great If its explained why

Comment: You're querying by `partitionKey`, so Cassandra will already know which nodes to query, no?

Comment: No that is in case I am not using the secondary index, As per the video, he mentions that If we use secondary Index then It does the query on all the nodes of Replication Factor without considering the Read Consistency. Is it true? Have u tried this ?

Comment: It was a wild comment from what I thought was right. I'll check video out. Alternatively, I'd suggest mocking cluster up, running query in DevCenter and checking execution plan. It should tell what happens during execution.

Comment: Thanks, @Evaldas, Will be expecting your response. Also, Is it possible for you to give a comment on how the secondary index table will look?

Comment: So it's as I thought. Using secondary keys means running queries against them. For instance `SELECT * FROM users WHERE secondary_key = 12345;` this will be a scatter-gather. Querying by partition key is still going to make use of the primary key and ignore secondary index.

Comment: Sorry, @EvaldasBuinauskas I reframed the question. I believe you got the question so what is that scatter-gather means in using secondaryColumn in query? Why it is not just reading from just two nodes (If read consistency is 2)? Why it is trying to read from all the nodes?

Comment: Secondary indexes are local to the that specific node. If you query by secondary index key, query engine doesn't know where those key values exist yet and on which nodes.

Comment: Can you please give me some example in Answer, It would be Great. Thanks

Comment: Also explain what secondary indexes in local means?

Comment: RC just needs to have atleast two nodes up and running. But if you search query through secondary indexes, it is like asking the cluster as where Can I find this data as I did not search via primary key. Then, it creates index on that column and gives you data from all possible nodes, which decreases the performance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cassandra will contact nodes until it reaches the LIMIT of rows to return, that satisfy your query, OR until it contacts all nodes. It does this by first contacting one node on the first round, two nodes on the 2nd round, four nodes on the third-round, and so on, starting with the node that contains the first token.

You can check the complete algorithm in this article (section E): https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cassandra-native-secondary-index-deep-dive

One thing to look out for when using secondary indexes is if the indexed column has a high cardinality because this will create massive indexes, and hence use a lot of disk space. Avoid using secondary indexes on these columns.

Comment: I am accepting his answer, Since the link he provided clearly explain the concept :)

Comment: I posted two questions on Cassandra, Would you please help me : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48519880/performance-impact-in-using-camelcase-in-cassandra-columns

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48519373/too-many-columns-in-cassandra

Answer (score 2):

To fill the discussion from comments:

Both up-to-date queries will be executed on two nodes because you're supplying partition key. By doing that Cassandra Query Engine can know in what exact node that data lives.

If you were to run the following query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM user
WHERE secondaryKey = "test";
```

This would run in all of your nodes that your table has data in and would have to scan each node based on that secondary key.

Like I said, secondary keys are local to node, which means if you'd have users table and your information would look somehow like that:

```
user_id  user_name
---------------------------
1        a_very_cool_user
2        a_very_cooler_user
3        the_coolest_user
```

So if we'd partition this data into three partitions, assume that each of these three nodes would have one row only:

- node 1 would have a_very_cool_user
- node 2 would have a_very_cooler_user
- node 3 would have the_coolest_user

And if you were to index `user_name` field, then node 1 would have indexed just a_very_cool_user and would not know what's in the other two nodes. Same applies to the other ones.  That's what local secondary indexes do in Cassandra.