# Too many columns in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have 20 columns in a table in Cassandra. Will there be a performance impact in performing

```
select * from table where partitionKey = 'test';
```

I am not able to understand from this link,

https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/CassandraLimitations

1) What will be the consequence of having too many columns (say 20) in the Cassandra tables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you have a lot of rows on the partition, I don't see an impact with having 20 columns. As stated in the documentation that you linked:

> The maximum number of cells (rows x columns) in a single partition is 2 billion.

So, unless you are expecting to have more than 100 million rows in a single partition, I don't see why 20 columns would be an issue. Keep in mind that Cassandra is a column family store. This designation means that Cassandra can store a large number of columns per partition.

Having said that, I would personally recommend not to go over 100 MB per partition. It might bring you problems in the future with streaming during repairs.

===============================

To answer to your comment. Keep in mind that partitions and rows are 2 different things in Cassandra. A partition is only equal to a row if there's no clustering columns. For instance, take a look at this table creation and the values we insert, and then look at the sstabledump:

```
create TABLE tt2 ( foo int , bar int , mar int , PRIMARY KEY (foo , bar )) ;
insert INTO tt2 (foo , bar , mar ) VALUES ( 1, 2, 3) ;
insert INTO tt2 (foo , bar , mar ) VALUES ( 1, 3, 4) ;
```

sstabledump:

```
./cassandra/tools/bin/sstabledump ~/cassandra/data/data/tk/tt2-1386f69005bd11e89c0bbfb5c1157523/mc-1-big-Data.db 
[
  {
    "partition" : {
      "key" : [ "1" ],
      "position" : 0
    },
    "rows" : [
      {
        "type" : "row",
        "position" : 32,
        "clustering" : [ "2" ],
        "liveness_info" : { "tstamp" : "2018-01-30T12:57:36.362483Z" },
        "cells" : [
          { "name" : "mar", "value" : 3 }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type" : "row",
        "position" : 32,
        "clustering" : [ "3" ],
        "liveness_info" : { "tstamp" : "2018-01-30T12:58:03.538482Z" },
        "cells" : [
          { "name" : "mar", "value" : 4 }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Also, if you use the `-d` option, it might make it easier for you to see the internal representation. As you can see, for the same partition, we have 2 distinct rows:

```
./cassandra/tools/bin/sstabledump -d ~/cassandra/data/data/tk/tt2-1386f69005bd11e89c0bbfb5c1157523/mc-1-big-Data.db 
[1]@0 Row[info=[ts=1517317056362483] ]: 2 | [mar=3 ts=1517317056362483]
[1]@32 Row[info=[ts=1517317083538482] ]: 3 | [mar=4 ts=1517317083538482]
```

Comment: To understand the internals, How are the cells related to rows and columns here? I checked the sstabledump and I am able to see each row has its own list of cells so How come we compare the cells to partition then ?

Comment: Thanks, But what is the point in having two rows? How it is related to cells?

Comment: You store several rows in the same partition in case you want to retrieve them in the same query. Due to how Cassandra distributes the data, you should aim to query only one partition. By storing several rows in the same partition, you don't need to fall into the anti-pattern of querying more than one partition.